# What REs can I use with =~ operator

Tags: bash, regular-expression

The [man page for `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) has this to say about the `=~` operator:

> An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same precedence as == and !=. When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in [regex(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regex))

However, I'm finding that even trivial REs don't appear to work. Here is my use case example:

```
n='hello'
[[ "$n" =~ 'llo' ]] && echo yes || echo no   # <-- yes
[[ "$n" =~ 'llo$' ]] && echo yes || echo no  # <-- no
```

Given that `$` is a standard RE indicator for EOL, why does the second comparison return "no"?

Comment: remove the quotes around the RE

Comment: @1_CR thank you. For my example your suggestion works. How would one include a space in the RE pattern without the quotes? Example `n='hello world'; [[ "$n" =~ 'lo world$' ]]`

Comment: I would stick the RE into a variable and use it, like so `var='lo world$';[[ "$n" =~ $var ]]`

Comment: @roaima, `[[ $n =~ "lo world"$ ]]` -- the literal chars are in quotes, the RE metachars are not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't read the man page carefully, it also said:

> Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string.

So the `$` in your string means the literal dollar sign instead of end of string. Moving the `$` from the string to make it work:

```
$ [[ "$n" =~ 'llo'$ ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
```

Comment: Oh I definitely read it carefully. Clearly just not carefully _enough_, thank you. More usefully, I don't think I'd registered the intent of that sentence. My reasoning was that an RE is a string, so quoting it would prevent the shell trying to evaluate variables, split at spaces, etc.

Comment: @roaima: glob+split wasn't performed inside `[[...]]`.

Comment: The bash manual is VERY densely packed with information: every sentence is meaningful. You definitely have to be on your toes and read and re-read to catch the meaning.